# php email verification using secret key

Tags: php

I've created a hash in confirm_email.php

```
$email = "blah@blah.com";
$secret = "$#@%^&$#$%^&&akeif"; //random characters
$hash = MD5($email . $secret);
$message = "https://localhost/mysite/register.php?email=" . $email . "&hash=" . $hash;
```

and then sends the email. Upon clicking the link, I have the following code in register.php

```
$secret = "$#@%^&$#$%^&&akeif";

if(isset($_GET['hash']) and (MD5($_GET['email'] . $secret) == $_GET['hash'])) {
    //allow registration to continue processing

} else {
    //don't allow
}
```

Should I use sessions to store the secret (I guess I could create a user-specific secret if this were the case)? Or, is there a better way entirely to to create a hash for this approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should only need the secret key in 2 places

Comment: I advise you put the secret in a config file, use `require_once` for the page that needs it. By using this method, you can unified the `secret` in different script. Furthermore, you can use `authcode` or other similar function/library to do a confirmation time control, if you need it.

Comment: *"Should I use sessions to store the secret"* - No, it should be a one-shot deal and with a time restraint.

Comment: You could also urlencode the email address http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I would suggest that the key is something far more complex and random. It's possible that this hash could be bruteforced and then password resets could be done against any emails with ease.

Comment: the only way it could be bruteforced, is in regards to rainbow tables and they'd have to hack into the database and/or be a middle-man when the email goes through, or they have access to a person's email area.

Comment: `authcode` can find at [here](https://gist.github.com/GeHou/4378709), a pretty small and efficient stream cipher script, but remember set the `$ckey` value to `16` to avoid Reused Key Attack. Another approach is hashing, same as what you mentioned, but a bit different, find my example [here](http://pastebin.com/ny2yycLb).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I've taken everyone's suggestions to heart. The secret is in a separate file that's included and the email gets urlencoded. I also included the time in the URL and compare the times on my register.php page.

```
if(($time_now - $_GET['time'] < 1800) and MD5($_GET['time'] . $secret) == $_GET['time_hash']) {
    $expired = false;
}

if(isset($_GET['hash']) and (MD5($_GET['email'] . $salt) == $_GET['hash']) and !$expired) {
    //allow registration to continue processing
}
```

Comment: do not put the `$secret` in the hashing function, it cause security problems, better to use `hash_hmac()`, get more info by read [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1070) article